# phpMyAdmin, despite easy mysql client connections to the database, cannot connect w/same credentials

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, openbsd

Just to preface, I have looked through the different threads on *phpMyAdmin* not being able to connect to a database, and I have found none that have the specific situation nor utilities that I have used; the troubleshooting procedures that I have found on here are all ones that I have tried, and nothing is working.

So, to get into the meat of the matter, here is what I've got going on.

I've got an *OpenBSD* server, version **5.6** (currently latest stable), and I've got *mysql-server*, *mysql-client*, and *phpMyAdmin* installed on this machine.  I had been doing some previous work with the database on there, since I lost my last one, so I wiped and reinstalled the entire database system with the appropriate utilities from scratch.

Upon creation of the database, I went and added accounts such as *'root'@'localhost'*, and *'root'@'connectionip'* (the IP address of another machine that connections may come from, though I believe localhost is the only relevant one as the php to connect comes from that machine), and *'root'@'connectiondns'*, all with the same password.

In order to simplify things, I tried enabling authorization with my simple & unsecure password via the config file, where the password and account are both defined.  **'#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock' (62) The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).'** was the resultant error message.

This after verifying that the *mysqld_safe* server, as well as active socket are both running and in place.  I even went so far as to compensate for a potential chroot environment by nginx, creating with `mkdir -p /var/www/var/run/mysql/` so that I could symbolic link the sock to that directory as well.  Anyway, I changed to config level auth next...

I then changed auth to cookies, and attempted logging in interactively.  Error message at this point became: **'#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server'**, this with the proper password (the one that I've used for absolutely every MySQL account in order to avoid potential confusion while troubleshooting).  It seems to me like the config file definition attempt is going farther, but I'm kind of lost here.

If anybody could recommend some troubleshooting steps, or where I might find more detailed information on this, I would truly appreciate it.  From the exact same machine, mysql's client program is connecting just fine with the username and password that I'm using while showing me everything that I need to see.  :P

Any help is very much appreciated.  Please feel free to ask for more details; I'm not sure if I should dump a config file here right away, but I'll throw in as much as I can here just in case:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '7 character hex redacted'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'redacted';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

And nothing below that line has changed.  At one point I even changed the password to blank and tried to allow no password.  That gave me the same errors as I was getting before.

Comment: Does it work if you add root@127.0.0.1 instead of localhost ?

Comment: Did you try writing a simple PHP script running from the same web server and trying to connect with these credentials?